# Transit VISA for US from India via London

Tags: usa, uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I know this is a kind of duplicate question but my scenario is bit different and I am looking for the answer as per my scenario.

My parents will be travelling from India to New York via London after 2 weeks, their flight has a layover of 2.5 hours at London - Heathrow. Their next flight will be departed from the same airport i.e. from London - Heathrow after 2.5 hours but before mid-night of same day (as per schedule of flight). They have a valid B1/B2 visa for United States.

Do they need for transit visa at London-Heathrow. I have already gone through link "https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa"
but some says that Indian passport holders need transit visa. Please let me know if they require it or not.

Comment: yes, it is a possible duplicate, I have gone through the link too, but can you let me know if it is required or not in my case?

Comment: When you answer the questions from the site linked in the possible duplicate, what are you getting stuck on?

Comment: At the third step 'Will you pass through UK Border Control?' and whether I select YES or NO, I always get 'You need a VISA'.

Comment: @Dhiman Did you read all of it? Should say something about a TWOV concession for certain visa holders (eg US visa holders)...

Comment: No, I didn't read about TWOV, but will go through it and if have further doubts will come back to stack exchange.

Comment: When you get to the part that say "You need a visa", there is a list of exceptions underneath it.

Comment: Why are you passing through UK border control? You should not need to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any one with an Indian passport on his/her way to USA or Canada does not need a transit visa for [UK if the USA or Canadian visa is a sticker one one of the pages in their passport](https://www.worldtravelforum.co.uk/threads/do-i-need-a-british-transit-visa.4/) and not a piece of paper that people have to carry with the passport. I know this sounds weird but that is how transit visa requirements for UK are checked when I board a flight for USA or Canada from New Delhi.